# Angular 6 Universal does not wait for finishing resolver

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I just installed Angular Universal start kit **version 6** and created my component in it. This component should get users info by an API on load and show it to view.

Problem is the API result is showing in the browser but not show in "**view source**". What is the Universal benefit so?!

My `getUserscommponent` code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-get-users',
  templateUrl: './get-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-users.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class SportFixturesComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.route.data.subscribe( data =>{
            if (data) {
                this.usersList = data;
            }else{
                this.usersList = [];
            }
        })          
    });
  }
}
```

In the `app.module.ts` codes:

```
import { getUserscommponent } from './get-users-component';
import { getUsersResolver } from './get-users-resolver';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    getUserscommponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'my-app'}),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { 
        path: 'get-users', 
        component: SportFixturesComponent ,
        resolve  : {fxResolvedList:getUsersResolver} ,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]),
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [getUsersResolver],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the `get-users-resolver` codes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute , Router , Resolve , ActivatedRouteSnapshot , RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class getUsersResolver implements Resolve<any>{

    constructor(private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute,private httpClient:HttpClient){}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot , state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
        interface fxInterface{
            status   : boolean ,
            users : any
        }
        return this.httpClient.post("/api/get-users" , {} , {})
    }
}
```

When I view source of for example **About Us** I see:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-about-view>
    <h3>About Us text... </h3>
  </app-about-view>
</app-root>
```

But when I view source I **Get Users Component** see:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet></app-root>
```

Even there is no

Could you please help me to figure this out.

Edited:

**And after some edits, now I got this error:**

```
    ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:813:31)
    at resolvePromise (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:770:17)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:872:17)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:420:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3934:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:419:36)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:187:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:594:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:499:21)
    at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js?:484:48)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:619:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:23)
  rejection: [Error],
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Error] },
  zone:
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent:
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate:
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
        _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _hasTaskZS: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
        _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
  task:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Error] },
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

Comment: Check that you have no error server side.

Comment: There were some but now, there is no error. The time I faced some errors was something like this: ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///1:813:31)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///1:770:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///1:872:17)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///1:420:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///7:3917:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///1:419:36)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///1:187:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///1:594:35)....

Comment: @David I appended the error I`v got in back-end  to the question.

Comment: Why are you using a `post` to **get** users? And when using angular universal, urls should be **absolute**

Comment: What do you mean absolute? This is my URL  /get-users/studens/germany/middleage.  You mean I could not use url params? And another question is it`s working in browser but not in view source

Comment: By absolute I mean `http://server.com/get/users/germany/middleage`

Comment: @David I changed to absolute URL and the Uncaught error disappeared. but I still have the universal problem. On this route I even can not see the tag <app-get-users></app-get-users>

Comment: @David I updated my answer again. Now I'm facing new errors that I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I fixed it by adding checking is it Browser into resolve return, like:

```
// resolver.ts
import { Injectable, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
...
...
export class ContentResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
        private http: HttpClient,
        ) {}

    resolve() {
        return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) ? this.http.get('some-url') : null;
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `"bundleDependencies": "all"` to your `angular.json` in the `server -> options` part of it.

Found this comment on a [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200#issuecomment-388387118)

Comment: This will create other problems on build, so it's not an solution

Comment: mind sharing those? so it can help whoever gets here as you did