# Observable never completes in Resolver

Tags: angular, observable, resolver

I am trying to implement a resolver so that my API data is resolved before loading a component. The observable returned from my HTTP request in my service is never completing, causing routing to hang. I have scoured tutorials and Angular documentation to see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas? I have generalized some of the code (just some naming) but shouldn't affect how it works.

This is my resolver service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PageResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(
    private service: MyAPIService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.service.getPage(route.url[0].path);
  }
}
```

This is my routing module (it is not the `app-routing.module.ts`, but rather a "child"):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-path',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
      page: ResolverService,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: OtherComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [ResolverService],
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

My service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyAPIService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getPage = (slug: string): Observable<Page[]> => {
    const uri = "https://my.com/URI"
    return this.http.get<Page[]>(uri);
  };
}
```

And my component:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  page: Page = null;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.page = data.page[0];
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I can't even get anything output to the console in my component constructor. I am able to get data if I change my resolver to

```js
return of(this.service.getPage(route.url[0].path));
```

and change my component to

```js
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      data.page.subscribe((page) => {
        this.page = page[0];
      });
    });
```

but then the data loads after my component does and I get errors in the console that it can't read `property "title" of null` (`page` is initialized to null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56280405/11790081

Turns out it was an issue with Angular Universal and SSR. Simply adding a check for `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` to produce a conditional return in the resolver solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First move that peace to `ngOnInit`

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.page = data.page[0];
    });
```

Rid out of arrow function in the class.

What does your endpoint return, array of Pages or only Page?

Set proper return type
and add tap operator to debug your endpoint

```
 public getPage(slug: string): Observable<Page[]> {
    const uri = "https://my.com/URI"
    return this.http.get<Page[]>(uri).pipe(tap(console.log));
  };
```

Angular's httpClient completes when value is emitted, if you want manually complete observable try `take(1)`

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.service.getPage(route.url[0].path).pipe(take(1));
  }
```

> I can't even get anything output to the console in my component constructor. I am able to get data if I change my resolver to

Don't do nested observables

```
return of(this.service.getPage(route.url[0].path));
```

Basically you are wrapping your http request in Observable and then you subscribe in the component twice which where second subscription is http request

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => { // this.activatedRoute.data = of()
      console.log(data);
      data.page.subscribe((page) => { // data.page = this.service.getPage()
        this.page = page[0]; // this subscription trigger http request
      });
    });
```

Comment: Looking at [these comments](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10556#issuecomment-240284735), I've tried both `of(observableFromHTTPRequest)` as well as `take(1)` or `first()` with no luck. I understand that I was wrapping an observable with an observable which doesn't make much sense, but it was the only way I could get the wrapped observable to complete, it seemed. Needless to say, `take(1)` does not solve this issue for me. When I tap into the return from the `resolve` method, I cannot get anything emitted to the console with `tap((resp) => console.log(resp))`.